# Postgresql json like and extract query

Tags: json, postgresql

I have the following table called **list_error**. Currently, it has many lines of entries:

| ID | error |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"cause": [{"code": "item.attribute.dropped", "type": "warning", "message": "Attribute: GTIN was dropped because its value_id and value_name are null, empty strings or they were not sent", "cause_id": 000, "department": "items", "references": ["item.attributes"]}, {"code": "item.attributes.missing_required", "type": "error", "message": "The attributes **[MODEL]** are required for category XXXXX. Check the attribute is present in the attributes list or in all variation's attributes_combination or attributes."} |

The idea is to be able to filter data that have "The attributes **[MODEL]** are required" in the error field. And also that it can extract from the entire text only the part "The attributes [MODEL] are required"

I'm trying to query it using `like` operator. Something like the following: `SELECT id, error from list_error where error::json->>'error' like '%MODEL'`

If anyone has any advice.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query.

You need to use **json_array_elements** to expands a JSON array.
after that you can access fields.

```
SELECT
    id,
    each_cause ->> 'message'
FROM
    list_error 
    CROSS JOIN json_array_elements (error -> 'cause') each_cause
WHERE
    each_cause ->> 'type' = 'error'
AND each_cause ->> 'message' LIKE '%MODEL%'
;
```